# How to apply deletion of records from API to the app connected to this API?

Tags: android, sql-delete, android-room, android-architecture-components

My Android app is connected to an API. It fetches data, it stores in the device's database, and if the device has no connectivity it will display the data from the local database as a well-behaved app. Now, the issue is that if I delete something in the remote server, it will not reflect on the device's database. It's a Django API with MySQL hosted in PythonAnywhere.com.

Below is the method in the repository of the activity that fetches data and stores it in the database of the device.

```
fun fetchPosts() {
    remote.fetchPosts()
        .doOnNext { posts -> local.insert(posts) }
        .onErrorResumeNext { _: Throwable -> Observable.fromCallable { local.fetchPosts() } }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { outcome.success(it) },
            { error: Throwable -> outcome.failed(error) }
        ).addTo(compositeDisposable)
}
```

Is there something to be done? I guess wiping out all the data in the local database and insert the new data wouldn't be very good, but I can't think of another alternative.

Comment: Hello @gamofe. I think you could try to implement some condition to check if the item in local databese is not present in the server response and then you should remove it. Other options is clear the local db when you are fetching data  and then insert all items from the last call.

Comment: Hello @gamofe, It is similar to my quiz app .I am using this algorithm.Algorithm is get all question and their versions(Versions are increasing when any changes).
1.Insert: If question id does not includes in local database then insert
2.Update: If question id is includes but not equal to local question versions then update
3.Get local database question ids and remove all ids which has got in server. After removed ids delete them(because ids is not includes in server).
Hope this helps

Comment: @gamofe Does it help to you ?

Comment: Yes it gives an idea of using Kotlin's `contentEquals` and `minus`.

Comment: Ok @gamofe, Good luck. I am using Java